Bash declare not liking values with spaces
This is a continuation of awk gsub not replacing all instances of period in field.
I have some input:
$ cat ./ipv4settings.txt
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)

I'm able to generate the desired output (somewhat):
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print $1"="$2 }' ./ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1
ipv4_routes=--
ipv4_route_metric=-1
ipv4_route_table=0 (unspec)

What I want to do next is declare variables for each line of output. I have used several variations using declare:
$awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print $1"="$2 }' ./ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1
ipv4_routes=--
ipv4_route_metric=-1
ipv4_route_table=0 (unspec)
$ declare $( awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print $1"="$2 }' ./ipv4settings.txt )
-bash: declare: `(unspec)': not a valid identifier

I tried quoting the entire line of output from awk (declare not a valid identifier bash)(https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-print-quote-characters):
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print "\042"$1"="$2"\042" }' ./ipv4settings.txt
"ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1"
"ipv4_routes=--"
"ipv4_route_metric=-1"
"ipv4_route_table=0 (unspec)"
$ declare $( awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print "\042"$1"="$2"\042" }' ./ipv4settings.txt )
-bash: declare: `"ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1"': not a valid identifier
-bash: declare: `"ipv4_routes=--"': not a valid identifier
-bash: declare: `"ipv4_route_metric=-1"': not a valid identifier
-bash: declare: `"ipv4_route_table=0': not a valid identifier
-bash: declare: `(unspec)"': not a valid identifier


... or just the value portion:
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print $1"=\042"$2"\042" }' ./ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway="192.168.2.1"
ipv4_routes="--"
ipv4_route_metric="-1"
ipv4_route_table="0 (unspec)"
$ declare $( awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub("[.]|-","_",$1);$1=$1;print $1"=\042"$2"\042" }' ./ipv4settings.txt )
-bash: declare: `(unspec)"': not a valid identifier

How do I get declare to work with a variable value with a space?

only value must be quoted, not variable name.

NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about. This tag is for questions about scripts written for the Bash command shell. Questions about the interactive use of Bash are more likely to be on-topic on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or Super User than on Stack Overflow.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

@aenagy, note that the accepted answer has been updated since you first accepted it; the new version avoids some security problems, so if you're using it in real-world code, you'd do well to use the current version.

@LéaGris Noted about http://shellcheck.net/. Thanks.

Modifying my answer to OP's previous question:
$ cat ipv4.awk
BEGIN { sq = "\x27" }

#######
# if 1st field will convert to an invalid variable name then print
# a message to stderr (printing to stdout will cause problems with
# the follow-on source call)

! ($1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]._-]+:/) {

        print "ERROR: Invalid entry:",$0 > "/dev/stderr"
        next
}

/^ipv4[.](gateway|route)/    {

        pos   = index($0,":")
        var   = substr($0,1,pos-1)
        value = substr($0,pos+1)

        gsub(/[.-]/,"_",var)
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/,"",value)
        gsub(sq,sq "\"" sq "\"" sq,value)             # see NOTES below

        print var "=" sq value sq
}

NOTES:

pertaining to the gsub(sq,sq "\"" sq "\"" sq,value) call ...
per the back-n-forth comments with Charles Duffy this additional gsub() call has been added to address potential injection attacks
Charles Duffy's proposed gsub(/[']/,"'\"'\"'",value) could also be used but must be placed in a file (eg, ipv4.awk) and invoked via awk -f ipv4.awk; calling gsub(/[']/,"'\"'\"'",value) from an inline awk script (eg, OP's example awk scripts) will generate syntax errors (due to the special nature of the single quote for inline awk scripts)

Adding some additional (bogus) lines on the end (borrowing a few from Charles Duffy's answer):
$ cat ipv4settings.txt
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routes:                            should ignore this line
ipv4.route-wifi.network-ssid-name:      hi$(touch evil)'$(touch evil)'\
ipv4.route-evil.variable.$(touch evil): harmless
ipv4.route-example.with.colons:         hi:world: yup: still data
ipv4.route-stuff:0   (unspec)  *   "'leave:these:colons:alone   

NOTE: the last line has a few spaces on the end
Generating the variable=value pairs:
$ awk -f ipv4.awk ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway='192.168.2.1'
ipv4_routes='--'
ipv4_route_metric='-1'
ipv4_route_table='0 (unspec)'
ipv4_route_wifi_network_ssid_name='hi$(touch evil)'"'"'$(touch evil)'"'"'\'
ERROR: Invalid entry: ipv4.route-evil.variable.$(touch evil): harmless
ipv4_route_example_with_colons='hi:world: yup: still data'
ipv4_route_stuff='0   (unspec)  *   "'"'"'leave:these:colons:alone'

One idea using source to load the variables into the current environment:
$ source <(awk -f ipv4.awk ipv4settings.txt)
ERROR: Invalid entry: ipv4.route-evil.variable.$(touch evil): harmless

$ typeset -p ipv4_gateway ipv4_routes ipv4_route_metric ipv4_route_table ipv4_route_wifi_network_ssid_name ipv4_route_example_with_colons ipv4_route_stuff
declare -- ipv4_gateway="192.168.2.1"
declare -- ipv4_routes="--"
declare -- ipv4_route_metric="-1"
declare -- ipv4_route_table="0 (unspec)"
declare -- ipv4_route_wifi_network_ssid_name="hi\$(touch evil)'\$(touch evil)'\\"
declare -- ipv4_route_example_with_colons="hi:world: yup: still data"
declare -- ipv4_route_stuff="0   (unspec)  *   \"'leave:these:colons:alone"


If you replace any instances of a single quote in the input data with a sequence like '"'"' or '\'', then I'd call this safe. Otherwise it's an injection attack waiting to happen.

OP's 'data' is coming from a nmcli / show call; while not an exhaustive search I've not found any sample outputs that include single quotes; do you have any examples of said output showing single quotes, or is this a question of someone/something jumping in and modifying OP's intermediate file (ipv4setings.txt) between the nmcli call and the source <(awk ...) call?

I don't trust nmcli output to be safe -- OP may not control the names of wireless networks, for example. Safer to assume anything not controlled only by a trusted human is actively malicious -- that way one avoids even unexpected/unforeseen attacks -- and besides, answers we give here are expected to be reused by others, outside the original domain; something that relies on details of the original context for safety limits its ability to be used outside that context.

That one additional gsub would look like gsub(/[']/, "'\"'\"'", value); the single quote is the only character that needs escaping in a single-quoted string in POSIX-compliant shells. (Granted, for proper paranoia one might also want to filter the key names; the native-bash answer I just added does that).

ok, I think I see where the issue is arising (on my behalf) ... as long as we're embedding the additional gsub() call within a file (eg, ipv4.awk) and then calling via awk -f ipv4.awk ... there are no issues; in OP's case the awk script is being called from the command line in which case the proposed gsub() call blows apart the entire script, and this is where I was looking at the 'messy' escaping issue (from a single quote perspective)

I'm still a bit fuzzy as to why my approaches failed. Also, @CharlesDuffy the exercise to sanitize would be an entirely different matter. For this question my focus was to get the variables declared.

@aenagy enable debug mode (set -xv) then run your declare $(awk ...) commands; the debug output will show you what bash is seeing which should be (fairly) clear as to why the error messages are being generated; for example, your first declare $(awk ...) is presented to bash as declare ... ipv4_route_table=0 '(unspec)', which generates an error about the standalone (unspec) being an invalid identifier

Your 2nd attempt is just wrapping quotes around too much.  And while your 3rd attempt appears to be wrapping just the value component, all of your coding attempts suffer from an issue with how bash word splits the $(awk ...) results before passing them to the declare; while there may be a way to get a declare $(awk ...) construct to work, alternative approaches are provided in this answer (source) and Charles Duffy's answer (printf -v variable value)

@aenagy, I cannot disagree more strongly with the idea that "sanitization" is a separate step from functional data-processing code. The last Fortune 50 company I worked for was constantly having major security bugs found in their products because they insisted on taking that approach: When you view input sanitization as a separate step, all security bugs become sanitization bugs; but that's an unworkable approach in the first place, because to sanitize data you need to know how it's going to be used and make sure it's safe for those contexts[...]

@aenagy, ...and if "sanitized" data is used in a different context than it was sanitized for, that sanitization no longer applies -- even worse is when the needs of the sanitization don't align with the underlying problem domain (which is how we get names like O'Brian being disallowed by code that takes innately broken approaches to sanitizing data for inclusion is SQL). By contrast, do it right at point-of-use (which is when you know what kind of handling is necessary -- often not escaping at all but just keeping code and data out-of-band from each other), and no sanitization is needed.

In native bash, avoiding the security issues implicit with source or eval:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
regex='^([[:alnum:]._-]+)[:][[:space:]]+([^[:space:]].*)$'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || {
    echo "WARNING: Unrecognized line: $line" >&2
    continue
  }
  varname=${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}
  varname=${varname//[-.]/_}
  printf -v "$varname" %s "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  [[ $debug ]] && declare -p "$varname" >&2
done <ipv4settings.txt

If run with debug=1, given your stated input, this outputs:
declare -- ipv4_gateway="192.168.2.1"
declare -- ipv4_routes="--"
declare -- ipv4_route_metric="-1"
declare -- ipv4_route_table="0 (unspec)"


Malicious inputs are either ignored or treated as data without being parsed as code:
wifi.network-ssid-name:      hi$(touch evil)'$(touch evil)'\
evil.variable.$(touch evil): harmless
example.with.colons:         hi:world: yup: still data

...emits:
declare -- wifi_network_ssid_name="hi\$(touch evil)'\$(touch evil)'\\"
WARNING: Unrecognized line: evil.variable.$(touch evil): harmless
declare -- example_with_colons="hi:world: yup: still data"

Notice how the $(...) sequences were assigned as data, not executed as code; no file named evil was created.

@markp-fuso, ...so, we ignore lines where the left-hand side of the : isn't valid (via the regex), and the right-hand side is treated as literal data so there's nowhere it could possibly get parsed as code -- it just gets assigned no matter whether it's something that might want to be malicious.

would something along that shown below be suitable?
(NB:using gnu awk !GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0))
$ cat ipv4settings.txt
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                        0 (unspec)

$ cat fixme.awk
{printf("%s=\"%s\"\n",gensub(/[\.-]/,"_","g",$1),gensub(/ {2,}/,"","g",$2))}

$ awk -F: -f fixme.awk ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway="192.168.2.1"
ipv4_routes="--"
ipv4_route_metric="-1"
ipv4_route_table="0 (unspec)"



You should mention that requires GNU awk or some other awk variant that supports the non-standard gensub() function.

Double quotes are a bad idea here -- they make for a larger set of strings that need to be escaped to prevent injection attacks.

@EdMorton, the poster uses gnu awk - see the original post, but appreciate your feedback.

@ticktalk, answers are written for more than just the OP -- we're building a knowledgebase here with the idea that people can find and reuse preexisting answers and so not need to ask new questions themselves -- so the disclaimer remains relevant.

while this helps the OP implement proper quoting, it doesn't actually perform the declarations (ie, OP's main requirement)
